# MySQL COUNT on WHERE Statement

Tags: mysql, count

Pleas help me on why COUNT condition on WHERE statement commits an error, and how could i fix it?.

```
         SELECT jq.taskqueueid,jq.jobid
           FROM (SELECT p.taskID `curentTaskID`,
                    p.taskName `currentTaskName`,
                    p.processingType `currentProcessingType`,
                    p1.taskID `prevTaskID`,
                    p1.taskName `prevTaskName`,
                    p1.processingType `prevProcessingType`
                  FROM projecttask p
                  LEFT JOIN projecttask p1
                    ON p.sequenceNo=p1.nextTaskSequence
                   AND p.projectID=p1.projectID
                 WHERE p.taskID=18) task
           INNER JOIN taskslogs tl
              ON tl.taskID=task.`prevTaskID`
             AND tl.statusDefinitionID=1
           INNER JOIN jobqueue jq
              ON tl.taskqueueid=jq.taskqueueid
           WHERE COUNT(jq.taskqueueid)=COUNT(tl.taskqueueid)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Here is the error: Query : SELECT jq.taskqueueid,jq.jobid         FROM (SELECT p.taskID `curentTaskID`,               p.taskName `currentTaskName`,        ...
Error Code : 1111
Invalid use of group function

Comment: You can't do a COUNT() without grouping your results.

Comment: I've also try to group it but same error encounted

Comment: What are you trying to do here? On the surface it seems odd that you want to select `taskqueueid` when the quantity of `jq.taskqueueid` is the same as the quantity of `tl.taskqueueid`.

Comment: yeah, i want to select all the jobs with the same quantity (taskslogs vs. taskqueue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) like COUNT() you need to do a grouping of data, if you want to use it as a condition you can't use WHERE for this, since WHERE conditions are considered before aggregation. Use GROUP BY with HAVING instead. (see also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html )